# Incomplete .xls to .txt conversion

Tags: java, excel, text, xls

Hello I am making a program to convert from .xls to .txt. My program works almost to perfection. It inserts into text well but the thing is it does not insert the xls file completely. It does not insert the last 20 rows. The xls I need to convert contains 1548 rows, of which 1528 are inserted correctly in the format I want. It seems weird to me that only 20 rows don't get inserted. Any ideas?

```
public class create_text_doc {
public void writing() {
    try {
        File textgen = new File("C:\\Users\\darroyo\\Desktop\\expru.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(textgen);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);    
        Writer w = new BufferedWriter(osw);

        String FilePath = "C:\\Users\\darroyo\\Desktop\\saldos_to_conv.xls";
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
        Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(fs);
        Sheet hoja = wb.getSheet("Contratos");
        int totalNoOfRows = hoja.getRows();
        int totalNoOfCols = hoja.getColumns();
        w.write("\n");
        for (int row = 1; row < totalNoOfRows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < totalNoOfCols; col++) {
                System.out.print(hoja.getCell(col,row).getContents() + "\t");
                w.write("Deposito por Saldo Inicial|"+hoja.getCell(0,row).getContents()+"|EFECTIVO| | |0|0|0|0|0|0|0|"+hoja.getCell(1,row).getContents()+"|"+
                new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())+"|0|"+
                new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())+"|0|0|"+hoja.getCell(3,row).getContents()+"|"+
                new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())+"|0|0\n");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Problem writing txt file");
    } catch (BiffException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[]args) {
    create_text_doc write = new create_text_doc();
    write.writing();
}
}
```

The system.out.println in my for loop prints out all the rows correctly, the problem is when I put them in the text document. I thought it could be the problem but after removing it, I am still missing 20 rows.

Comment: You forgot to close the writer.

Comment: Upon further debugging, I found that it inserts each row 5 times as well, but I don't know what causes it.

Comment: That's not surprising, assuming there are 5 columns.

Comment: LMAO after searching for a while, wow, brainfart xD

Comment: closing the writer fixed it, thanks..